# Is it possible to destructure in case for use in a threading macro?

Tags: clojure

```
(def val { :type "bar" })

(-> val
  (case ???
    "bar" "bar type"
    "baz" "baz type"
    "other type"))
```

I'd like to include a `case` in a threading macro so I can branch based on one of the keys of `val`, a hash map. Is this possible?

EDIT: I need to thread `val` not a key from val as further functions will need the whole of `val`. I essentially want to branch to a function within the threading macro based on a key of `val`. But still pass `val` onward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a multimethod dispatch here:

```
(defmulti some-operation :type)

(defmethod some-operation "bar"
  [val]
  (println "Bar type!")
  (assoc val :x 42))

(defmethod some-operation "baz"
  [val]
  (println "Baz type!")
  (assoc val :x 100))

(-> {:type "bar"}
    some-operation
    some-other-operation)
```

Comment: You could also use `(-> val :type (case ,,,))` if `val` is something more complicated.

Comment: Thanks @SamEstep -- added your example above with credit

Comment: I should add that I need `val` as is for the next set of fn's. I will update the question to make this clear.

Comment: I am a bit unsure how to phrase the question, but I think I have some sort of answer which I will post to maybe help clarify.

Comment: @Kris I understand your question. I will modify and include the old info for reference

Comment: Multimethod looks promising, I will try this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is something which seems to work and serves as a better example of what I want to do:

```
(def val { :type "bar" })

(-> val
  (do-something-to-val-based-on-type)
  (do-something-else-to-val))

(defn do-something-to-val-based-on-type [val]
  (let [:type (:type val)]
    (case type
      "bar" (do-something-to-bar-type-val val)
      "baz" (do-something-to-baz-type-val val)
      val))) ;; default, no-op

(defn do-something-to-bar-type-val [val]
;; something
val)

(defn do-something-to-baz-type-val [val]
;; something
val)
```

Comment: Ah, I incorrectly assumed that you were writing a pure function. In this case, I think you want [`doto`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto) rather than `->`.

Comment: what makes it not "pure", I have no side effects?

Comment: I must be misunderstanding. If you have no side effects and the function always returns `val`, then what is the difference between your function and the `identity` function?

Comment: I guess this would be going of on a tangent, but doesn't 'side effects' refer to changes outside the function, e.g. Disk/Network IO?

Comment: @Kris No; if a function modifies its argument in a way that is visible to the caller, then that is a side effect and the function is impure.

Comment: Aren't the arguments immutable?

Comment: @Kris If they are, and you perform no other side effects, then as I said before, I see no difference between your function and the `identity` function. If `do-something-to-bar-type-val` and `do-something-to-baz-type-val` just return `val`, and `val` is immutable, then unless I'm misunderstanding something, the only way they can have any meaning is if they perform side effects.

Comment: I think we have different definitions of "pure function" :) My definition would be for given inputs you always get the same outputs, i.e. no mutable global state is involved (Time, IO etc.). In Clojure values are immutable by default, mutation is explicit and used for performance reason AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

also, since a threading macro simply adds an item to a seq for every "action", you can easily use anonymous function for that:

```
user> (def val { :type "bar" })
#'user/val

user> (-> val
          ((fn [{type :type}]
             (case type
               "bar" "bar type"
               "baz" "baz type"
               "other type"))))
;;=> "bar type"
```

if you wish, you can also make up special macro, rearranging `let` for usage in `->`:

```
user> (defmacro let-inv [x binding & body]
        `(let [~binding ~x] ~@body))
#'user/let-inv

user> (-> val
          (let-inv {type :type}
            (case type
              "bar" "bar type"
              "baz" "baz type"
              "other type")))
;;=> "bar type"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is easily accomplished using the `it->` threading macro [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#literate-threading-macro):

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def val { :type "bar" })

(println "result => "
  (it-> val
    (case (grab :type it)
      "bar" "bar-type"
      "baz" "baz-type"
      "other-type")))
```

to yield the desired result:

```
result =>  bar-type
```

The `it->` macro assigns the intermediate value to the symbol `it` at each stage of the pipeline. In this case we use the `grab` function to extract the `:type` value. It works like `(:type it)` but will throw if the key is not found.

Another example:

```
(it-> 1
      (inc it)                                  ; thread-first or thread-last
      (+ it 3)                                  ; thread-first
      (/ 10 it)                                 ; thread-last
      (str "We need to order " it " items." )   ; middle of 3 arguments
;=> "We need to order 2 items." )
```

Comment: What's the difference between `it->` and [`as->`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/as-%3E)?

Comment: They are similar, except `it->` copies a good idea from Groovy and always names the threaded value `it`.  Also, `as->` always seemed a bit backwards to me in defining the placeholder symbol.

Comment: If the differences between a macro in `clojure.core` and a macro from your library are just stylistic, then your answer should really just point to the one in `clojure.core` and maybe mention your library as an afterthought.

Comment: Actually, I had forgotten about `as->` since I hadn't used it in so long....  I'm surprised no one else mentioned it as an answer.

Comment: I think `as->` was meant to be nested within `->`. This explains why the placeholder is the second argument. If it had been the first, you would not be able to nest the threading macros together.